# Terminate and replace app with earlier version to do upgrade install

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, version, updates

I'm a newbie in Mac OSx & Objective-C development.

I'd like to ask some help on how to terminate as well as replacing an existing app (with an earlier version) when a later version of the app is being installed or upgraded?

I am aware about updating an app when a new version is available in the App Store or an external server. I've got that covered already. But this one is an implementation for a mac with no internet connection. Upgrading is done manually by installing the app whenever there's a new version available.

Behavior when installing:

1. It should check if there's an existing copy of the app in the system. It should prompt the user to continue and remove the app or cancel the installation.
2. If an existing copy of the app is currently running, it should prompt the user to quit the running copy of the app or cancel the installation. When the user selects to quit the app, it should automatically terminate the app and continue with the installation. The app with the previous version should be replaced by the newly installed copy of the app with the later version.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PackageMaker can do all of this for you. Prepare an installer using this app by Apple. If you are using Mountain Lion then download it from

https://developer.apple.com/downloads "Auxiliary tools for Xcode"

Launch the application and click the edit button in the actions tab below preinstall actions.

[image]

In the sheet that is presented add the Quit application action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is there any other way to do this? I'm using Disk Utility to create a dmg file for the installer because PackageMaker is a little bit buggy.

Comment: The only other solution that I can think of is to write your own Installer app or depend on the Finder to warn the user about an existing copy. I've been using PackageMaker for a long time and never found it buggy. Drag and Drop installers using DMG will not be able to achieve what you are expecting.

Comment: I see...I'm using 10.6.8. By the way, can you please state the complete workflow of the Preinstall actions?

Comment: I've edited my answer to add new images showing the proper work flow with an example.

Comment: I could just kiss you right now, Suhas! Thanks man! You just saved my life. LOL. Seriously, though...thanks! :D